# Positioning of p-values in numeric `corrplot`

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

**UPDATED**

I would like to have the p-values centered and underneath the correlations in a numeric `corrplot`.

```
library(corrplot)
M = cor(mtcars[ , 1:4])

testRes = cor.mtest(mtcars[ , 1:4], conf.level = 0.95)$p

## specialized the insignificant value according to the significant level
corrplot(
M,      
method = "number",
insig = "p-value",
tl.pos = "lt",
p.mat = testRes, 
sig.level = -1
)
```

But as you can see, the function writes the p-values over top of the numerical quantities.

[image: Result]

Edits: Fixed typo `t1.pos` to be `tl.pos` (lowercase l) as users indicated below.

Comment: I get the error '"t1.pos" is not a graphical parameter', which is weird since `t1.pos` should be handled in the `corrplot` function, but the error I get sounds like it is being passed to `par`, i.e. as a plotting option. One work-around could be to use `mtext` to directly overlay the p-values onto your plot.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo: the input parameter is called: tl.pos; with the second character being the lowercase letter L (instead of the number 1).